# Using Eval() to evaluate a dynamic string, negative symbols that are spliced in aren't staying in the string

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a calculator for my AP Computer Science Principles class, and am running into an issue with my +/- button.

How I designed it was to find the last operator (+,-,*, or /) and then place a negative symbol right after to make the next set of numbers negative.

What's happening, however, is that my calculator displays a - sign in the correct position, but if I enter another number it basically overwrites the - sign, additionally, when the button is pressed to evaluate the string, it ignores the - sign. When the string is passed from the +/- function to the evaluating function I have the string log to console, and the - sign is gone and the output of the evaluating function isn't correct.

Here's my codepen link: https://codepen.io/chogge/pen/PEqBGr

```
function plusMinus(displayNumber) {

var indices = [];
if(displayNumber==0){
    displayNumber = displayNumber;
} else{
    for(var i=0; i<displayNumber.length;i++) {
        if (displayNumber[i] == "-" || displayNumber[i] == "+" || displayNumber[i] == "*" || displayNumber[i] == "/") indices.push(i+1);
    }
    var maxx = Math.max.apply(null, indices);
    if(maxx == -Infinity){
        maxx = 0;
    }
    console.log(maxx);
    var splicedNumber = displayNumber.splice(maxx,0,"-");
    console.log(splicedNumber + ' ' + displayNumber);
    display(splicedNumber);
    }
}

function display(displayNumber) {
  var a = document.getElementById('display');
  if(displayNumber == 'Infinity'){
    displayNumber = "Error: Divide by Zero";
  }
  a.innerHTML = displayNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you keep a double record of the expression to be evaluated: (1) the actual display (the `value` or `innerHTML` property of the DOM element with the id `"display"`, and (2) a global variable named `displayNumber`, which, in most of your code, is a copy of the actual display. Whenever you evaluate the display expression in the function `equals()`, you evaluate what is currently stored in the variable `displayNumber`. To work properly, this depends on the variable `displayNumber` to be in sync with the actual display.

Here is the problem: While the function `addToDisplay()` keeps both the actual display and `displayNumber` in sync, the function `plusMinus()` only updates the actual display, not the global variable. Then, when calling the `equals()` function, this does not evaluate what is currently displayed.

The optimal solution might be to avoid keeping a double record by discarding the global variable `displayNumber` and only read/write to the actual display. This would require a larger rewrite of your code.

Another solution would be to fix the `plusMinus()` function to update the global variable `displayNumber`. Since this function already declares a local variable named `displayNumber`, you would have to rename this to be able to write to the global variable with the same name.

This updated function should fix your problem:

```
function plusMinus(localDisplayNumber) { // local variable declared here
    var indices = [];
    if (localDisplayNumber == 0) {
        displayNumber = localDisplayNumber; // update global variable
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < localDisplayNumber.length; i++) {
            if (localDisplayNumber[i] == "-" || localDisplayNumber[i] ==
                "+" || localDisplayNumber[i] == "*" ||
                localDisplayNumber[i] == "/") indices.push(i + 1);
        }
        var maxx = Math.max.apply(null, indices);
        if (maxx == -Infinity) {
            maxx = 0;
        }
        var splicedNumber = localDisplayNumber.splice(maxx, 0, "-");
        displayNumber = splicedNumber; // update global variable
        display(splicedNumber);        // update actual display
    }
}
```